# Fail to export shapefile created from X,Y table

Tags: arcgis-10.0, shapefile, export

I have a dbf file with X,Y coordinates. I chose to display X, Y data in ArcGIS and got a temporary shapefile. However, when I try to export the temporary shapefile, I got an empty one.

There is nothing wrong with the titles of the variables in the table. And I tried to re-save the table in the other format and re-create the shapefile. It does not work.

Did anyone have this issue before? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps going into ArcCatalog and finding your dbf, rightclicking on then create feature class > From XY Table...  will give you what you need.

Comment: Thanks, Moggy. I just tried it in ArcCatalog. It generated an empty shapefile. I don't know why I can only create temparary shapefile which can well present.

Comment: Check your DBF lat and columns

Comment: Thanks Moggy! It is the problem of the lat and long. The coordinates don't have decimals. Though GIS can create shapefile from coordinates without decimals, it can't export the shapefile.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding decimal points to the geographic coordinates.